# grading with if else statement

Tags: java, javascript, if-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class grade   {
public static void main(String args[])       {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

double no;
System.out.print("Please enter your CPA: ");

no = input.nextDouble();

if (2.00<=no)//2.00<=CPA<= 2.49
System.out.println("forth class");

else if (2.50<=no)//2.50<=CPA<=2.99
System.out.println("third class");

else if (3.00<=no)//3.00<=CPA<=3.74
System.out.println("second class");

else if (3.74<=no)//(no>=3.75)
System.out.println("first class");

else
     System.out.println("You did not follow the order.");

     }  }
```

if i enter for example i enter the grade 3.5 it will print out the forth class, also if i gave 4.00 also it will print out the forth class. Why it didnt print out the exact answer?

Comment: 6 answers and no downvotes for an elementary logic problem. This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: i'm only a beginner :D @JhKaiz

Comment: I know, but think about the logic, you could solve it by yourself without those helps, you're better than you think dude. today is a good day, no downvote @ivy_lynx xD!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should. because `forth class` give by following lodic

```
if (2.00<=no)
 System.out.println("forth class");  // both 3.5 and 4.00 are satisfy this.
                                     // 3.5 >2.00 as well as 4.00>2.00
```

Now you can see your logic not correct. any value greater than `2.00` will satisfy this.

Just change your logic order

```
if (3.74 <= no) {
    System.out.println("first class");
} else if (3.00 <= no) {
    System.out.println("second class");
} else if (2.50 <= no) {
    System.out.println("third class");
} else if (2.00 <= no) {
    System.out.println("forth class");
} else {
    System.out.println("You did not follow the order.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get forth class because 3.5 and 4 are greater than 2, You better us a switch statement here.

Answer (score 0):

your first condition `if (2.00<=no)` evaluates to true for both 3.5 and 4.0. all the other clauses are skipped, that's how an if statement works :-)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add &&(and) in your if condition just like...

```
if (2.00<=no && no < 2.50)
 System.out.println("forth class");
```

Answer (score 0):

its a simple `if-else` statement problem. you forgot to set boundaries(range values) in your statements.

Comment: (3.00<=CPA<=3.74) like this?

Comment: for example if(no>= 3.00 && no < 3.74){ // first class or something } in first operation you bound the result to greater than 3.00 AND / MUST BE less than 3.74

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the expected output as you currently only check if it is over a certain number, try swapping the order and adding something like this to each statement:

```
if (no>=2.00 && no<=2.49)//2.00<=CPA<= 2.49
System.out.println("forth class");

else if (no>=2.50 && no<=2.99)//2.50<=CPA<=2.99
System.out.println("third class");

else if (no>=3.00 && no<=3.74)//3.00<=CPA<=3.74
System.out.println("second class");

else if (no>=3.75)//(no>=3.75)
System.out.println("first class");

else
System.out.println("You did not follow the order.");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the upper limit and the bottom limit

```
if (3.74 <= no) {
    System.out.println("first class");
} else if (3.74 > no && 3.00 <= no) {
    System.out.println("second class");
} else if (3.00 > no && 2.50 <= no) {  
   System.out.println("third class");
} else if (2.50 > no && 2.00 <= no) {
   System.out.println("forth class");
} else {
   System.out.println("You did not follow the order.");
}
```